# xor of Church-encoded booleans in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, xor

I'm currently trying to implement a lambda expression for xor. However, I feel like I'm missing something because I am getting errors from by bxor expression. What am I doing wrong?

```
true  = \t f -> t    -- always pick the first argument
false = \t f -> f    -- always pick the second argument

toBool = \b -> b True False

bnot = \b -> b true false

bxor = \b x -> b (bnot x) x
```

Comment: I believe `bnot` ought to be `\b -> b false true`.

Comment: What error do you get? I don't get one.

Comment: I guess the issue is that `bnot` has a complicated type `((t -> t1 -> t1) -> (t3 -> t4 -> t3) -> t2) -> t2` which makes the type of `bxor` even worse. This question should clarify what is the actual issue here. Compare it with `bnot = \b x y -> b y x` for instance.

Comment: http://ideone.com/KfaInH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a typed environment, one needs to be careful. Your lambda-terms work fine in an untyped setting, but need some tweaks in a typed one.

We need to define a type for Church booleans. Let's choose the following parametric monomorphic type.

```
type B a = a -> a -> a
```

Then, let's add type annotations to check what's wrong:

```
true :: B a
true  = \t f -> t

false :: B a
false = \t f -> f

toBool :: B Bool -> Bool
toBool = \b -> b True False
```

So far, so good. However:

```
bnot :: B a -> B a
bnot = \b -> b false true
```

yields a type error, since e.g. `false` has type `B a`, not `a`, so the application `b false` is ill-typed. We can work around this by adding a couple of `a` arguments `x y`, and simplifying the function accordingly.

```
bnot = \b x y -> b (false x y) (true x y)
-- or, more simply:
bnot = \b x y -> b y x
-- or even
bnot = flip
```

This type checks. Similarly, we can rework `bxor` to make it type check:

```
bxor :: B a -> B a -> B a       
bxor = \b1 b2 x y -> b1 (bnot b2 x y) (b2 x y)
```

---

Alternatively, using the *impredicative* Church encoding of booleans, we can make your original code to type check as it is, except for adding the relevant type signatures. This requires higher-rank types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

type BI = forall a. a -> a -> a

trueI :: BI
trueI = true

falseI :: BI
falseI = false

toBoolI :: BI -> Bool
toBoolI = \b -> b True False

bnotI :: BI -> BI
bnotI = \b -> b falseI trueI

bxorI :: BI -> BI -> BI
bxorI = \b x -> b (bnotI x) x
```